# Tensorflow probability: ValueError: Tensor's shape (2, 2) is not compatible with supplied shape (2,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I'm trying to get NUTS sampler working on a toymodel. I've run into the issue mentioned in the title.

This is the code to reproduce the error:

```py
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_probability import bijectors as tfb
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

tfd = tfp.distributions


A = tf.random.normal(
    [10,10], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, seed=None, name=None)
noise_std = tf.random.normal([1])

x1 = tfd.Normal(0, 10 * tf.ones(10)).sample()
x1 = x1[..., tf.newaxis]
y = tf.linalg.matmul(A, x1) + noise_std


model = tfd.JointDistributionSequentialAutoBatched([
    tfd.Normal(loc=0., scale=1.), #sigma 
    tfd.Normal(0, 10 * tf.ones(10)),
    lambda x_rv, sigma : tfd.Normal(loc=tf.linalg.matmul(A, x_rv[...,tf.newaxis]) + sigma, scale=1.0)
])

def target_log_prob_fn(sigma, x_rv):
    return model.log_prob([sigma, x_rv, y[tf.newaxis, ...]])


def trace_fn(_, pkr):  
    return (
        pkr.inner_results.inner_results.target_log_prob,
        pkr.inner_results.inner_results.leapfrogs_taken,
        pkr.inner_results.inner_results.has_divergence,
        pkr.inner_results.inner_results.energy,
        pkr.inner_results.inner_results.log_accept_ratio)

n_chains = 2

def run_nuts_template(
    trace_fn,
    target_log_prob_fn,
    inits,
    bijectors_list=None, 
    num_steps=500,
    num_burnin=500,
    n_chains=n_chains):
    
    step_size = np.random.rand(n_chains, 1)*.5 + 1.
    
    if not isinstance(inits, list):
        inits = [inits]
        
    if bijectors_list is None:
        bijectors_list = [tfb.Identity()]*len(inits)

    kernel = tfp.mcmc.DualAveragingStepSizeAdaptation(
        tfp.mcmc.TransformedTransitionKernel(
            inner_kernel=tfp.mcmc.NoUTurnSampler(
                target_log_prob_fn,
                step_size=[step_size]*len(inits)
            ),
            bijector=bijectors_list
        ),
        target_accept_prob=.8,
        num_adaptation_steps=int(0.8*num_burnin),
        step_size_setter_fn=lambda pkr, new_step_size: pkr._replace(
              inner_results=pkr.inner_results._replace(step_size=new_step_size)
          ),
        step_size_getter_fn=lambda pkr: pkr.inner_results.step_size,
        log_accept_prob_getter_fn=lambda pkr: pkr.inner_results.log_accept_ratio,
    )
    
    res = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
        num_results=num_steps,
        num_burnin_steps=num_burnin,
        current_state=inits,
        kernel=kernel,
        trace_fn=trace_fn
    )
    return res



inits = model.sample(n_chains)
run_nuts = partial(run_nuts_template, trace_fn)


inits = [tf.random.uniform(s.shape, -2, 2, tf.float32, name="initializer") for s in inits]

run_nuts(target_log_prob_fn, inits[:-1])
```

Error: ValueError: Tensor's shape (2, 2) is not compatible with supplied shape (2,)

Full stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/zAA58P53

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ab5eae0dd51a> in <module>
      3 ]
      4 
----> 5 run_nuts(
      6     target_log_prob_fn,
      7             inits[:-1]
 
<ipython-input-13-2d7a920574a8> in run_nuts_template(trace_fn, target_log_prob_fn, inits, bijectors_list, num_steps, num_burnin, n_chains)
     45     )
     46 
---> 47     res = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
     48         num_results=num_steps,
     49         num_burnin_steps=num_burnin,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/sample.py in sample_chain(num_results, current_state, previous_kernel_results, kernel, num_burnin_steps, num_steps_between_results, trace_fn, return_final_kernel_results, parallel_iterations, seed, name)
    359       return seed, next_state, current_kernel_results
    360 
--> 361     (_, _, final_kernel_results), (all_states, trace) = mcmc_util.trace_scan(
    362         loop_fn=_trace_scan_fn,
    363         initial_state=(seed, current_state, previous_kernel_results),
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/internal/util.py in trace_scan(loop_fn, initial_state, elems, trace_fn, trace_criterion_fn, static_trace_allocation_size, parallel_iterations, name)
    462       return i + 1, state, num_steps_traced, trace_arrays
    463 
--> 464     _, final_state, _, trace_arrays = tf.while_loop(
    465         cond=lambda i, *_: i < length,
    466         body=_body,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    603                   func.__module__, arg_name, arg_value, 'in a future version'
    604                   if date is None else ('after %s' % date), instructions)
--> 605       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    606 
    607     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_value_notice_to_docstring(
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop_v2(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, maximum_iterations, name)
   2487 
   2488   """
-> 2489   return while_loop(
   2490       cond=cond,
   2491       body=body,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name, maximum_iterations, return_same_structure)
   2733                                               list(loop_vars))
   2734       while cond(*loop_vars):
-> 2735         loop_vars = body(*loop_vars)
   2736         if try_to_pack and not isinstance(loop_vars, (list, _basetuple)):
   2737           packed = True
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/internal/util.py in _body(i, state, num_steps_traced, trace_arrays)
    452     def _body(i, state, num_steps_traced, trace_arrays):
    453       elem = elems_array.read(i)
--> 454       state = loop_fn(state, elem)
    455 
    456       trace_arrays, num_steps_traced = ps.cond(
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/sample.py in _trace_scan_fn(seed_state_and_results, num_steps)
    352 
    353     def _trace_scan_fn(seed_state_and_results, num_steps):
--> 354       seed, next_state, current_kernel_results = mcmc_util.smart_for_loop(
    355           loop_num_iter=num_steps,
    356           body_fn=_seeded_one_step,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/internal/util.py in smart_for_loop(loop_num_iter, body_fn, initial_loop_vars, parallel_iterations, unroll_threshold, name)
    346       # where while/LoopCond needs it.
    347       loop_num_iter = tf.cast(loop_num_iter, dtype=tf.int32)
--> 348       return tf.while_loop(
    349           cond=lambda i, *args: i < loop_num_iter,
    350           body=lambda i, *args: [i + 1] + list(body_fn(*args)),
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    603                   func.__module__, arg_name, arg_value, 'in a future version'
    604                   if date is None else ('after %s' % date), instructions)
--> 605       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    606 
    607     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_value_notice_to_docstring(
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop_v2(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, maximum_iterations, name)
   2487 
   2488   """
-> 2489   return while_loop(
   2490       cond=cond,
   2491       body=body,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name, maximum_iterations, return_same_structure)
   2733                                               list(loop_vars))
   2734       while cond(*loop_vars):
-> 2735         loop_vars = body(*loop_vars)
   2736         if try_to_pack and not isinstance(loop_vars, (list, _basetuple)):
   2737           packed = True
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/internal/util.py in <lambda>(i, *args)
    348       return tf.while_loop(
    349           cond=lambda i, *args: i < loop_num_iter,
--> 350           body=lambda i, *args: [i + 1] + list(body_fn(*args)),
    351           loop_vars=[np.int32(0)] + initial_loop_vars,
    352           parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/sample.py in _seeded_one_step(seed, *state_and_results)
    349       one_step_kwargs = dict(seed=step_seed) if is_seeded else {}
    350       return [passalong_seed] + list(
--> 351           kernel.one_step(*state_and_results, **one_step_kwargs))
    352 
    353     def _trace_scan_fn(seed_state_and_results, num_steps):
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/dual_averaging_step_size_adaptation.py in one_step(self, current_state, previous_kernel_results, seed)
    454       # Step the inner kernel.
    455       inner_kwargs = {} if seed is None else dict(seed=seed)
--> 456       new_state, new_inner_results = self.inner_kernel.one_step(
    457           current_state, inner_results, **inner_kwargs)
    458 
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/transformed_kernel.py in one_step(self, current_state, previous_kernel_results, seed)
    397         self.name, 'transformed_kernel', 'one_step')):
    398       inner_kwargs = {} if seed is None else dict(seed=seed)
--> 399       transformed_next_state, kernel_results = self._inner_kernel.one_step(
    400           previous_kernel_results.transformed_state,
    401           previous_kernel_results.inner_results,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/nuts.py in one_step(self, current_state, previous_kernel_results, seed)
    392           )
    393 
--> 394       _, _, _, new_step_metastate = tf.while_loop(
    395           cond=lambda iter_, seed, state, metastate: (  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
    396               (iter_ < self.max_tree_depth) &
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    603                   func.__module__, arg_name, arg_value, 'in a future version'
    604                   if date is None else ('after %s' % date), instructions)
--> 605       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    606 
    607     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_value_notice_to_docstring(
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop_v2(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, maximum_iterations, name)
   2487 
   2488   """
-> 2489   return while_loop(
   2490       cond=cond,
   2491       body=body,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name, maximum_iterations, return_same_structure)
   2733                                               list(loop_vars))
   2734       while cond(*loop_vars):
-> 2735         loop_vars = body(*loop_vars)
   2736         if try_to_pack and not isinstance(loop_vars, (list, _basetuple)):
   2737           packed = True
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/nuts.py in <lambda>(iter_, seed, state, metastate)
    396               (iter_ < self.max_tree_depth) &
    397               tf.reduce_any(metastate.continue_tree)),
--> 398           body=lambda iter_, seed, state, metastate: self._loop_tree_doubling(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
    399               previous_kernel_results.step_size,
    400               previous_kernel_results.momentum_state_memory,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/nuts.py in _loop_tree_doubling(self, step_size, momentum_state_memory, current_step_meta_info, iter_, initial_step_state, initial_step_metastate, seed)
    570           momentum_subtree_cumsum,
    571           leapfrogs_taken
--> 572       ] = self._build_sub_tree(
    573           directions_expanded,
    574           integrator,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/nuts.py in _build_sub_tree(self, directions, integrator, current_step_meta_info, nsteps, initial_state, continue_tree, not_divergence, momentum_state_memory, seed, name)
    750           final_not_divergence,
    751           momentum_state_memory,
--> 752       ] = tf.while_loop(
    753           cond=lambda iter_, seed, energy_diff_sum, init_momentum_cumsum,  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
    754                       leapfrogs_taken, state, state_c, continue_tree,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    603                   func.__module__, arg_name, arg_value, 'in a future version'
    604                   if date is None else ('after %s' % date), instructions)
--> 605       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    606 
    607     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_value_notice_to_docstring(
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop_v2(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, maximum_iterations, name)
   2487 
   2488   """
-> 2489   return while_loop(
   2490       cond=cond,
   2491       body=body,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name, maximum_iterations, return_same_structure)
   2733                                               list(loop_vars))
   2734       while cond(*loop_vars):
-> 2735         loop_vars = body(*loop_vars)
   2736         if try_to_pack and not isinstance(loop_vars, (list, _basetuple)):
   2737           packed = True
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/nuts.py in <lambda>(iter_, seed, energy_diff_sum, init_momentum_cumsum, leapfrogs_taken, state, state_c, continue_tree, not_divergence, momentum_state_memory)
    758                       leapfrogs_taken, state, state_c, continue_tree,
    759                       not_divergence, momentum_state_memory: (
--> 760                           self._loop_build_sub_tree(
    761                               directions, integrator, current_step_meta_info,
    762                               iter_, energy_diff_sum, init_momentum_cumsum,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/nuts.py in _loop_build_sub_tree(self, directions, integrator, current_step_meta_info, iter_, energy_diff_sum_previous, momentum_cumsum_previous, leapfrogs_taken, prev_tree_state, candidate_tree_state, continue_tree_previous, not_divergent_previous, momentum_state_memory, seed)
    811           next_target,
    812           next_target_grad_parts
--> 813       ] = integrator(prev_tree_state.momentum,
    814                      prev_tree_state.state,
    815                      prev_tree_state.target,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/internal/leapfrog_integrator.py in __call__(self, momentum_parts, state_parts, target, target_grad_parts, kinetic_energy_fn, name)
    295           next_target,
    296           next_target_grad_parts,
--> 297       ] = tf.while_loop(
    298           cond=lambda i, *_: i < self.num_steps,
    299           body=lambda i, *args: [i + 1] + list(_one_step(  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter,g-long-lambda
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    603                   func.__module__, arg_name, arg_value, 'in a future version'
    604                   if date is None else ('after %s' % date), instructions)
--> 605       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    606 
    607     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_value_notice_to_docstring(
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop_v2(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, maximum_iterations, name)
   2487 
   2488   """
-> 2489   return while_loop(
   2490       cond=cond,
   2491       body=body,
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name, maximum_iterations, return_same_structure)
   2733                                               list(loop_vars))
   2734       while cond(*loop_vars):
-> 2735         loop_vars = body(*loop_vars)
   2736         if try_to_pack and not isinstance(loop_vars, (list, _basetuple)):
   2737           packed = True
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/internal/leapfrog_integrator.py in <lambda>(i, *args)
    297       ] = tf.while_loop(
    298           cond=lambda i, *_: i < self.num_steps,
--> 299           body=lambda i, *args: [i + 1] + list(_one_step(  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter,g-long-lambda
    300               self.target_fn, self.step_sizes, get_velocity_parts, *args)),
    301           loop_vars=[
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/internal/leapfrog_integrator.py in _one_step(target_fn, step_sizes, get_velocity_parts, half_next_momentum_parts, state_parts, target, target_grad_parts)
    353               next_target_grad_parts))
    354 
--> 355     tensorshape_util.set_shape(next_target, target.shape)
    356     for ng, g in zip(next_target_grad_parts, target_grad_parts):
    357       tensorshape_util.set_shape(ng, g.shape)
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/internal/tensorshape_util.py in set_shape(tensor, shape)
    326   """
    327   if hasattr(tensor, 'set_shape'):
--> 328     tensor.set_shape(shape)
    329 
    330 
 
~/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in set_shape(self, shape)
   1213   def set_shape(self, shape):
   1214     if not self.shape.is_compatible_with(shape):
-> 1215       raise ValueError(
   1216           "Tensor's shape %s is not compatible with supplied shape %s" %
   1217           (self.shape, shape))
 
ValueError: Tensor's shape (2, 2) is not compatible with supplied shape (2,)
```

The only variable with shape of (2, ) is `sigma`, but I was not able to figure how is turns into a `(2, 2)` tensor.

Comment: If the `sigma` random variable is removed then the sampler works as intended and the posterior looks fine. I still can't figure out what's causing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the shapes of your step sizes. As written, the chain state parts have (including the `n_chains` batch shape) shape `[2]` and `[2, 10]`, resp. However your step sizes are all being initialized with shape `[2, 1]`. This is correct for the second state part (`[2, 1]` broadcasts with `[2, 10]`) but not for the first -- you end up with a `[2, 2]` somewhere, presumably in the `step_size * grad(tlp, state[0])` term (paraphrasing) in the integrator.

I rewrote the step size initialization to this, which could probably use some code-golfing, but works as intended:

```py
    step_size = np.random.rand(n_chains) * .5 + 1.
    step_size = [np.reshape(step_size, [n_chains] + [1] * (x.shape.ndims - 1))
                 for x in inits]
    # now step size shapes are [2] and [2, 1]
```

Some other notes:

1. Check out `tf.linalg.matvec` -- it will save you some chars (and possibly some flops) by avoiding the newaxis + matmul
2. it looks like you're doing stan-style initialization, with random inits in the `[-2, 2]^n` hypercube. In general you'll want to do this in the *unconstrained* space, so you will probably want to push those random init's through your constraining bijectors, at least when they're not the defaults (`Identity`). `TransformedTransitionKernel` assumes the user-provided states are in the *constrained* (sample) space. Hopefully this is clear...please let me know if not!
3. There's a new experimental feature, "pinning" that might simplify some things for you here. You'll want to first make sure your distributions have names (pass a `name` arg to the constructors), but then you can call `pinned = model.pinned(y=y)` to get an instance of `tfp.experimental.distributions.JointDistributionPinned`. You can use `pinned.unnormalized_log_prob` in place of your `def target_log_prob_fn` (it does the same thing), and you can also call `pinned.experimental_default_event_space_bijector()` to get a bijector that "just does the right thing" for transforming the un-pinned variables. Ie, you can just hand that thing off to `TransformedTransitionKernel`. It actually is a "multipart" (or "joint") bijector, so it eats lists and returns lists; you no longer need to list-wrap your passed-in bijector. TTK, as of recently, knows how to use these multipart bijectors. As the names suggest, these are all pretty new and experimental/subject to API tweaks, but should be in good working order; please let us know if you try them and run into issues!

Here's a colab w/ the slightly modified step size code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1o-nygALqdq2ppj5rU9d6UVafZM5SBCd4

HTH!